# xpath select inner text of an element which is repeated in random area of a xml file

Tags: c#, xml, xpath

I have a xml file like this **NEVER MINDE letter cases**. I am interested in elements that are inside  and ...and if there is a  element in a subchild of  I dont want to count taht in.

```
<document>
<tests>
<group>
  <number>
    <random>
      ....
      ....
      <pins>
      <pin>
        <number>1</number>
      </pin>
        <pin>
          <number>2</number>
          <result>
            <number>NOT INTERESTED</number>
          </result>
        </pin>
    </pins>
    </random>
  </number>
</group>
```

I worte the following methods to get the pins that I am interested(in this case 1 and 2)

```
    public int GetNumberOfAllPins()
    {
        string xpath = "count(/Document//Pins/Pin/Number)";
        int num = Convert.ToInt32(nav.Evaluate(xpath));
        return num;        
    }

    public string[] GetNameOfAllPins()
    {
        string[] temp = new string[GetNumberOfAllPins()];
        XPathNodeIterator it = nav.Select("/Document//Pins/Pin/Number");

        int i = 0;
        while (it.MoveNext())
        {
            temp[i] = it.Current.Value;
            i++;
        }
        return temp;
    }
```

But these codes gives me strange results sometimes less or more  elements that I am interested in. Would you mind givng some tips?

Thanks.

Comment: As a side note, you can use `foreach` on `XPathNodeIterator`.

Comment: Your XML has lowercased tags ("pin", "number"), but your XPath has them camel-cased ("Pin", "Number"). Is that a typo? If not, that's your answer right there - XML and XPath are case-sensitive.

Comment: @Pavel sorry for that, it was a typo...please dont mind case of XML file I provided that is just for reference

Comment: @Sean87: I don't understand what _"strange results"_ means...

Comment: @Sean: Well, all still needs to be accurate.

Comment: @Alejandro I mean  They are less or more elements I get actually when I try this code with different files. if I count them by hand they dont match

Comment: I suspect that my code also counts the <number> element which is inside <result> node. I want my code to stop counting them at /Pins/Pin

Comment: @Sean87: Different results for different documents? That's by definition... If the XPath engine doesn't select the nodes you want, it could be wether because there is a bug or your expression is wrong. I don't think it's the former, by the way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for bothering but I fount the problem. there were some adjacent elements in my XML file. this codes works good!

Comment: As a side note: constructing an array of length determined by `GetNumberOfAllPins` within `GetNameOfAllPins` in this manner is nigh-on lunacy ...use a `List<string>` instead and simply `Add` to it.

Comment: @Mr. Dissapointment Thanks for tip but I am new to C# I really dont know how to do it. I just used my PHP skills so far. would you mind giving a code example?!

Comment: No problem, here you go: http://pastebin.com/7ZdinXHf. Also w/ a couple of other elements you ought to look into. ;)